# Facebook omniauth "uninitialized constant SessionsController" routing error

Tags: omniauth

I am testing out facebook omniauth.  I followed the directions listed on https://coderwall.com/p/bsfitw
I followed all 6 setups listed:

1. Add Omniauth and Omniauth-Facebook gems.
2. Create User model.
3. Create Sessions controller
4. Create Omniauth initializer
5. Add client-side functionality using javascript.
6. Showing the logged in user in the View.

This is what my routes file looks like:
Rails.application.routes.draw do

routes.rb

```
root 'welcome#home'

get 'about'=>'welcome#about'

match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: [:get, :post]

match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/'), via: [:get, :post]

match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout', via: [:get, :post
```

sessions.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

 def create

  @user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])

  session[:user_id] = user.id

  redirect_to root_url

end

 def destroy

  @session[:user_id] = nil

  redirect_to root_url

 end

end
```

I searched through Google numerous times to search and unfortunately, I have not found any solutions that work.  Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was stupid mistaken on my part.  The sessions file must be added at "sessions_controller.rb" Otherwise it will produce this error.